# Gravity Forms within Forms

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

Within Gravity Forms there is the option to create an HTML block.

What I want to do is be lazy and create a collection of sub-forms or fieldsets (for example "Your Details") which contain elements that will be used on every form.

So I create a form with elements for "Your Details" (name, age, etc) and paste the shortcode for the sub-form into the HTML block of the main form. This generated html that included a nested `form` tag:

```
<form method="post" action="/?gf_id=2" <!-- other attributes -->>
    <!-- other elements -->
    <form method="post" action="/?gf_id=1" <!-- other attributes -->>
        <!-- other elements -->
    </form>
</form>
```

Is there a way to embed the form elements of subform (`gf_id=1`) into the main form (`gf_id=2`) without the form tags? I really do not want to have to recreate the "Your Details" section (about 20 elements) in every form (about 8 forms).

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to do this. Gravity Forms offers the ability to do AJAX or POST step forms.

So you would have three steps and have Your Details as step 1 etc.

You can access this within the form settings.

In regards to your question, I don't believe there is.